# Why don't wipers clean the entire windshield

Tags: windshield-wipers

The wiper blade doesn't cover all the way down to the corner.  I had my windshield replaced last year and have also tried replacing the wiper blades.

Here is a picture of it with rain on the spot where it would normally be clean:
[image]

Comment: When replacing the wipers, did you look up what size is supposed to go on the car?  Wrong size wipers can cause this.  Also, some wiper designs have the ability to flex more than others, so maybe yours are just too stiff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are showing is usually caused from the wiper arm not having enough down force to keep the blade on the entire swipe. This could be caused from the spring (which does this) losing its tension. The part of the windshield which you've shown is especially susceptible to this because of how the glass angles over.

If this scenario is right, there are two ways you can possibly "fix" this:

- Take the end of your wiper arm and bend it slightly towards the windshield. This will cause the tension spring at the base of the wiper arm to be stretched just a little more and thus cause more down pressure on the wiper.
- Replace the wiper arm. I don't think you can purchase "just" the tension spring, but you could see. Replacing either is going to be by far more expensive than the first option I've listed.

There is a possibility that the wiper arm has been bent back a little bit, so the first option would help in that scenario as well.

Comment: I bought an OEM wiper arm off ebay for $10 and replaced it, but this is still an issue.  Is it possible they installed the wrong windshield on my car?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the picture it's not an arm problem or you'd notice partial wipes once it start to lift up off the windshield. Honestly from the pic it looks like you need to go up an inch or two in length on the blades. Although... There are some cars now that have windshield edges that's so rounded off that all aftermarket blades are gonna have problems conforming to.

Answer (score 0):

Just bend the end of the windshield wiper to fit that little spot, should have better downforce on it then.